# Symfony session handler default location tries to create directory

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have a Symfony 3.3.5 application for which I want to use the default session handler:

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: null
```

However when I do this, Symfony tries to create the /var/lib/php/sessions directory, which already exists:

```
    [2017-08-01 14:24:37] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Session Storage was not able to create directory "/var/lib/php/sessions"" at /home/infoodlebiz/www/site/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/
Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/NativeFileSessionHandler.php line 52 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Session Storage was not able to create directory \"/var/lib/php/sessions\" at /home/infoodlebiz/www/site/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/NativeFileSessionHandler.php:52)"} []
```

I cannot see why this would be, the directory is world readable, writeable:

```
ls -la /var/lib/php/sessions/
total 176
drwx-wx-wt 2 root       root       110592 Aug  1 14:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root       root         4096 Oct 16  2016 ..
-rw------- 1 globalyear globalyear    305 Aug  1 14:04 sess_1u179qdaqcihhkmmi4qepj2na0
-rw------- 1 globalyear globalyear    305 Aug  1 14:15 sess_5p76n0falmf0rmogs4v2s9sss5
-rw------- 1 globalyear globalyear    304 Aug  1 13:49 sess_65i7jlca6ifhs8k1ucdkf8d091
-rw------- 1 cbc        cbc           213 Aug  1 14:28 sess_9hfobt8p6lu056avq2udiq7ck0
-rw------- 1 cbc        cbc           213 Aug  1 14:06 sess_b6mdvgj6v6ip1l1pi77upnc845
```

directory above is not

```
ls -la /var/lib/php/
total 124
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Oct 16  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x 49 root root   4096 Mar 29 13:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Oct 16  2016 modules
drwx-wx-wt  2 root root 110592 Aug  1 15:25 sessions
```

PHP is running as PHP-FPM under its own user name using sockets

Comment: What's the output of ls -la /var/lib/php? And web server running as?

Comment: Have updated question

Comment: How is the server writing the other session files? Is it because because they are owned by other users? [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695548/php-cannot-read-sessions-from-nfs-share/28568551)

Comment: All other sites are custom php sites and use the default session mechanism. they all have different users

Comment: Did you try php bin/console cache:clear? If that does not work, try to remote debug and step through or setup breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I had identical symptoms using *Apache 2.4* on a *CentOS 7*, running *php-fpm 7.1* by the way of module *fast-cgi*.

Sessions storage folder was configured to be `/var/lib/php/fpm/session`, and `/var/lib/php/fpm` is a remote folder mounted by `root` user throught *NFSv3*.
And finally `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` had following parameters:

```
user = apache
group = apache
```

In my case, even having added user `apache` into `php-fpm` group, and having settled `/var/lib/php/fpm/session` permissions as following

```
$ ls -lad /var/lib/php/fpm/session
drwxrwx--- 2 root php-fpm 487 dic  4 11:54 /var/lib/php/fpm/session
```

**In order to mitigate the error reported by *Symfony 2.7*, it was necessary to force *apache* user ownership of `/var/lib/php/fpm` and `/var/lib/php/fpm/session` this way:

```
chown apache /var/lib/php/fpm 
chown apache /var/lib/php/fpm/session
```

Hope it helps